# How to feed linux new install drivers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, drivers

I'm trying to install a Linux distribution on my new setup, but after the first tries I failed without knowing why.

> My configuration:

- Desktop PC HP
- Processor: Intel Core i3 2120 @3.30GHz
- Chipset: Intel Sandy Bridge
- Graphic Interface: NVIDIA GeForce GT 520

> My actions so far:

- 3 X installed Ubuntu 12.10 (64bit) - after boot I get an orange screen (some errors that convinced me to reinstall 3 times).
- tried to install Linux Mint, Mate 32bit but when the installer starts i can see nothing but a scrambled image.
- installed Linux Mint, Mate 64bit - after boot it hangs on some errors

Update:I saw some flashing errors about drivers not found.

After this tries i was thinking that i need to preload drivers for my configuration in installation files. 
How do i provide the linux boot disc with such information and where do I get those drivers?

Please tell me if you need more info for the drivers.

related to this: [Hardware problem after fresh Linux Mint install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56183/27212)

Is there any chance that i can make nvidia drivers avaiable for ubuntu from my windows install? or to put them somewhere to be avaiable for the intaller in order to see them?

Comment: Lets start with the most important:
"some errors that convinced me to reinstall 3 times"  what errors exactly?  And PCI-Express is not what would help, is the graphics card Radeon, Nvidia, Intel?

Comment: I've edited your answers, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, the first thing you should try is to install ubuntu and bootup with monitor plugged in integrated graphics card slot ( i3 sandy bridge comes with integrated graphics, they should probably work).

This looks like a good link about how to get nvidia card working, but this must be done within already installed ubuntu.

http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/

Am not a real specialist in ubuntu and never had a nvidia  card, but seems like it should help.

Reinstalling won't help here because you get the same software over and over again. :)

To get to the installed mint/ubuntu system from liveCD/usb you can follow this guide (it seems good) up to(including) step 6:

http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/02/how-to-chroot-to-ubuntu-using-live-cd-to-fix-grub-rescue-prompt/

but i would add an extra step 5.5 with a command:

```
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /media/xx..xx/etc/resolv.conf
```

After sudo chroot ... you will be in the installed system and can execute commands mentioned in previous link about nvidia driver installation.

Comment: i don't know how to "bootup with monitor plugged in integrated graphics card slot".

Comment: well, you metion in the question, that you are using Desktop PC, so at the back of the PC case there should be multiple connection places for monitors (? not sure about correct term).

Comment: i have 2 entries there vga & dvi, should i try one of them?

Comment: i'm running a windows machine now, is there a posibility to add the driver when in windows or to make the drivers avaiable to linux install on the flash drive with the bootable linux?

Comment: Well..no, but you could do it from the installation environment. When you put in the installation Cd, there is an option to boot without installing. Then, assuming the display works, you could chroot to the installed ubuntu and fix it.

Comment: I'm a bit out of my league with this suggestion, i want to try it, but i don't know how to chroot into another mint install from a live usb flash drive

Comment: Updated my answer with a link about how to chroot.