# Hardware problem after fresh Linux Mint install

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hardware, crash

I've installed Linux Mint, Mate 64bit on my machine.

> My configuration:

- Desktop PC HP Pro 3400 Series MT
- Processor: Intel Core i3 2120 @3.30GHz
- Chipset: Intel Sandy Bridge
- Graphic Interface: NVIDIA GeForce GT 520

My computer hangs on with a warning, here is a summary:

- Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on CPU 0
- after a list of modules : last unloaded module CSSI_wait_scan
- PID: 0, comm: swapper/0 Tainted
- After that there is a call trace.

Related to this: [How to feed linux new install drivers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55825/27212)

Comment: The entire call trace would be useful.

Comment: How can i obtain it? i shoot a picture with my camera ?

Comment: If you don't want to write it down …

Comment: Did the install update everything? Is there perhaps an older kernel that you could boot? Any hardware changes? Any hardware plugged in that you could remove to boot? Any tweaks to the kernel command line suggested by the installation?

Comment: Finally i installed OpenSuse and abandoned mint and ubuntu solutions; OpenSuse worked like a charm :)